# Which mode to use to draw on a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

Hi I am using bitmap and following code to erase arcs from bitmap

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
```

What should I do with mPaint now to make it draw on bitmap.

Comment: I did it using Mode.SCREEN

Answer (score 0):

Make separate methods like

// To clear arcs

```
void turnEraserOn(){ 
    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
}
```

// To draw again

```
void turnEraserOff(){
    mPaint.setXfermode(null);
}
```

and call them whenever needed.